# visual studio code version 1.63.2

Tags: javascript

in visual studio code version 1.63.2 I cannot type the letter (P) can someone help how to slove this issue and this letter shows in the bottom when need to type P "Cannot read property 'document' of undefined"?
Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not a product support community, You will need to contact Microsoft yourself, or post a bug-report to VSC's GitHub repo: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode

Answer (score 0):

Look in keyboard shortcuts for a shortcut with P, maybe accidentally there is one.